# How to retrieve total child from model class and pass in adapter in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I retrieved data from firebase realtime database and pass it to the adapter and show it in the recyclerview.
Below image shows my data structure.
[image: database structure]

lastname,postid and timestamp is succesfully retrieved by model class.
But I want to retrieve total no. of child of "comments" and pass in adapter.
Here is my model class.

```
public class Post
{
    public String lastname;
    public String postid;
    public long timestamp;

    public Postt()
    {

    }

    public Postt(String lastname, long timestamp, String postid)
    {
        this.lastname=lastname;
        this.timestamp=timestamp;
        this.postid=postid;
    }

    public String getPostid() {
        return postid;
    }

    public void setPostid(String postid) {
        this.postid = postid;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

And adapter is

```
List<Post> mPost;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostHolder postHolder, final int i) {
        String posid=mPost.get(i).getPostid();
        String lastname=mPost.get(i).getLastname();
        long timestamp=mPost.get(i).getTimestamp();
***//Here i want to get the total no of child of "comments" node.//
//please dont tell to use ValueEventListner inside onBindViewHolder//***
            }
```

Here is my query in MainActivity

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<Post> userModels = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       userModels.add(userSnapshot.getValue(Post.class));
//Here I want to retrieve no of "comments"child and pass in adapter//
                }
                mAdapter.addAll(userModels);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

For retrieving "comments" total no. of child, how i prepare model class and for loop in query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using firebase database 
I believe that you are using datasnapshot in order to get comments of particular post as you shown in your database structure.
When you get the datasnapshot after adding listener you will find that **dataSnapshot** will have method for children Count you can call it like this :

`dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`

Use that in the node which you get the comments from and you can then send after you get the list to the adapter.

Ref:[DataSnapshot_Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot)

Edited :

Your are now actually getting the whole Post node and you are only missing the comments part , you will need to add List with variable name comments along with it's setters and getters in your Post Class. like here but change Comment to the type of the comments String Object whatever you have the comment to be as a data type

```
public class Post
{
public String lastname;
public String postid;
public long timestamp;
public HashMap<String, YourCommentClassName> comments;
```

And in your onBindViewHolder will be something like this

```
List<Post> mPost;
     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostHolder postHolder, final int i) {
    String posid=mPost.get(i).getPostid();
    String lastname=mPost.get(i).getLastname();
    long timestamp=mPost.get(i).getTimestamp();
    // This will have the list of comments and the number of the comments 
    //you have
    long commentsNumber = 0
    if(mPost.get(i).getComments()!=null)
      commentsNumber=mPost.get(i).getComments().size();
        }
```

Comment: Hey guys please help me

Comment: I think comments makes hashmap not a list

Comment: yes  same concept you will get hashMap.size() of the comments as well adding it to the Post model class and then retrieving it in the onBindViewHolder using the same way @tailor

Comment: Ok i will try it

Comment: YourCommentClass means Comment Model class ?

Comment: Yes it does @tailor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196128/discussion-between-hossam-eldeen-onsy-and-tailor).

Comment: Currently on testing Posts node has 10 child and comments child is not mendatory of each nodes of posts